# Login failed : when I try to connect my database using only multi threading

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server, iis

Two methods in my code. Both methods, Connect same DB, execute same SP and return data according to the Input string

```
GetData("xxx");

GetData("xyz");
```

When I call these methods one by one it works fine. But when I try run these methods using separate threads it gives

```
Message: "Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication."
Number: 18452
```

Why this happening only through the threads and how can I resolve it? Please help.

Here is My Connection String

```
"server=DBServer;database=DataBaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;Pooling=True"/>"
```

Comment: Show code section where threads are created...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly a speculative guess, but It probably means you do not correctly impersonate the proper context in your threads. Most likely your ASP.Net thread is impersonating the caller, but your hand-started thread does not. You need to take the identity of your main thread and pass it to your concurrent threads and impersonate it in these worker threads. W/o this precaution your worker threads will operate under the app pool identity.

But the true gist is... **you absolutely don't need to do this at all**. If you want to place multiple calls in parallel, set [`AsynchronousProcessing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.asynchronousprocessing.aspx) to `true` and use [`BeginExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutereader.aspx). This way you can have multiple requests (on separate connections, still!) executing in parallel w/o having to worry about impersonation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply, please let me know how take the identity of main thread and pass it to concurrent threads and impersonate it in these worker threads.
I think this will resolve my problem/

Comment: I would recommend doing the async calls, is safer.

Comment: I am sorry, This application is based on .net 1.1, And seems it's not supported  AsynchronousProcessing to use BeginExecuteReader.So Think the first option is the only solution.

Comment: You need to pass current  [`CallContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext(v=vs.71).aspx) to your worker threads.